# Django Model : How to combine the reverse access sets from two foreignkey fields?

Tags: python, django

In my django models file, I have:

```
class Node(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Segment(models.Model):
   start = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='start_segments')
   end = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='end_segments')
```

From the Node object, I would like to access all segment objects, that have either start or end pointing to the node, from a single attribute name, like:

```
node_x.segment_set
```

However this is not possible as far as I could see. I have provided two different related_name-s only to avoid the error thrown otherwise. Otherwise, I would like to create a single set combining the two.

I can create a utility method which will return the combined set. However, it would not be available for queries. In my application, I often need to search considering all segments connected to the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a `QuerySet` you can make use of `Q` objects (see [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)).

```
from django.db.models import Q
results = Segment.objects.filter(Q(start=node_x) | Q(end=node_x))
```

To access that more quickly you can define it as a `property`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    @property
    def segments(self):
        return Segment.objects.filter(Q(start=self) | Q(end=self))
```

Now in your code you can retrieve the segments by accessing the `property`:

```
In [1]: print node_x.segments  # or print(node_x.segments) in Python 3
Out[1]: [<Segment: Segment object>, <Segment: Segment object>, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should either use

```
Segment.objects.filter(start=node_x) | Segment.objects.filter(end=node_x)
```

or

```
node_x.start_segments.all() | node_x.end_segments.all()
```